# export a xml file of my database based on a xsd file using cakephp

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, xsd

Hi i wondered if you can help me how to export a XML file of my database based on a XSD file, using CakePHP framework APIs
I have a .XSD schema file and here you can see it : http://alirezadesigner.com/My-Files/lvb_system.xsd
Also you can see my tables structures here:
[image: All tables and relations]
and I want to know the easiest wayhow to do that
thank you so much